# Can smart contract be used to enforce rule based auction?

Tags: solidity

I'm building a smart contract based auction system on top of ethereum, like [this example](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#blind-auction).  Instead of the highest bidding price, the system will use a function `f` to compute the most optimal bid.

E.g., if each bid is represented with parameters `(a, b, c)`, then the most optimal bid is the one that maximizes `f(a, b, c)`.

The questions I have are:

1. Is this system feasible on ethereum?
2. Can function `f` be updated in the future?  How difficult is it?
3. Is it possible to pin a specific `f` for a contract, so attackers cannot implement a different function `g` and disrupt the decision making process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this system feasible on ethereum?

Probably yes, but it's hard to say, because it is still not clear to me what is your algorithm of function `f`.

> Can function f be updated in the future? How difficult is it?

No. Once smart contract is deployed to Ethereum you cannot change its functions.

> Is it possible to pin a specific f for a contract, so attackers cannot implement a different function g and disrupt the decision making process?

The funciton `g` that you are referring to can only be implemented outside of your deployed contract instance. In this case function `g` can only affect the state of your contract only if one of your functions can change the state and this functionality is not regulated by some modifiers like `onlyOwner()` or by limiting visibility (e.g. internal, private).